# Is it ok to Brine a turkey ahead of roasting time

Tags: turkey, brining

I would like to brine my turkey on Tuesday. Take it out of the brine Wednesday, rinse it and keep it in the refrigerator until I roast it on Thursday. Is this ok?

Comment: Welcome -- are you asking if it's food safe, or if it will cook well? :)

Comment: Trader Joe's sells pre-brined turkeys which are held refrigerated for 2-3 weeks. I don't see why it should be a problem.